# why is my timedelta math off?

Tags: python, datetime

I couldn't find anything online and probably has some stupid simple answer, but being new to python I don't understand:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now_utc = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcnow())
past = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(seconds=120))
delta = (now_utc-past).seconds
print delta # prints '119', not '120'
```

Why does it always print 1 second less than the timedelta I specify? If I change "seconds=120" to "minutes=1", I get '59', not '60'. Why?

Comment: You're calling datetime.utcnow() twice. It seems silly that the two calls take place 1 second apart, but why not try a single call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> print now_utc - past
0:01:59.999976
```

So there is 119 seconds and 999976 microseconds. Because you did two separate `datetime.utcnow()` calls with a little (24 microseconds) interval.

Comment: that's it. I should only make it 1 time. I feel stupid. I'll accept your answer in 9 minutes when I am allowed.